# Qt - QString Numerical Format String (cformat), Options?

Tags: qt, qstring

I have user-provided format string (e.g. "%.2f") and a QVariant type that I am attempting to combine to output into a (formatted) string.

I had gone down the path of using QString::asprintf(const char *cformat, ...) to achieve this, where I would supply the appropriate converted data type, like this:

```
QString result_str = QString::asprintf(disp_fmt.toUtf8(),variant_type.toUInt());
```

This works fine for the most part, especially when I have a floating point as the input.  However, if my format string in this particular *integer* (.toUInt()) conversion case includes decimal formatting (e.g. "%.2f"), then I get a constant result of "0.00".  This caught me by surprise as I expected to instead just get ".00" tacked onto the integer, as I have seen in other languages like Perl.

What am I missing here?  Also, I know asprintf() was added fairly recently and the documentation already now advises to use QTextStream or arg() instead.  I don't believe this to be an option, however, for me to use this style of format string.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string is expecting a `double`, but you're providing an `int`. It works if you provide an actual double, like this:

```
QString result_str = QString::asprintf(disp_fmt.toUtf8(),variant_type.toDouble());
```

Also note, this behavior is identical to how the standard C library functions work (`std::sprintf`, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  I was attempting to hold the QVariant explicitly to the type put into it (like UInt could only be extracted with toUInt()), but see that it will convert using toDouble as you say, satisfying the expectation for the double input.  This now works as expected.  Thanks!